# Ruby on Rails : generate erb html web page and can access database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm quite new to Ruby on Rails, so many simple things that I cannot do it. Here is my problem that I face. In rails, when I generate a database, rails will generate a bunch of erb html file for this database. (view, edit, add, delete etc).

Now, I want to add another erb file and satisfied two conditions. Firstly, It can use this database. For more detail, it can use this structure without config it:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %> 
# product is a row in table products
```

And, secondly, browser can browse to this erb html file. For example:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/myfile
```

I think those action is really easy, but because I learn ruby on rails by tutorial, I cannot do those stuff. Please help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Basically you're asking how to work with Ruby on Rails. I'd look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is hard to follow, but if I understand correctly then you need to:

- Add a new member route to the Products resource in `routes.rb` - see [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)
- Create a new view in `app/views/products` matching the name of the new route